# R package not building due to package name

Tags: r, build, package

I am trying to build a package in R Studio but after navigating to the package directory I get the following error:

```
> build()
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD build '/Users/alexander/Desktop/CitiBikeTools' --no-resave-data  \
  --no-manual 

* checking for file ‘/Users/alexander/Desktop/CitiBikeTools/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
Error in if (pkgname != intname) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
```

All of the necessary files are in the package and I double checked the description file and there are no extra or missing characters in the title.  What else could be causing this error?

Comment: can you cut & paste the first few lines of `DESCRIPTION` ?  alternatively, try setting `options(error=recover)` and interrogating `pkgname` and `intname` when you get to the error point ...

Comment: A naked call to `build()` fails with `Error: could not find function "build"` on a recent version of RStudio Version 1.0.44 on a mac running El Cap . You have not documented this adequately